# Cannot create a multi line arrays in AutoHotkey

Tags: dictionary, automation, autohotkey

I am fairly new to ahk and I've run into a bit of a problem.
No matter what I try, I cannot get arrays to span multiple lines.

Is this a limitation of AHK itself or is this due to me not understanding the grammar correctly?

An example:

```
TypeHandler := [
  {"pattern": "=[0-z]*", "callback": "HandleEIN"},
  {"pattern": "&[0-z]*", "callback": "HandleProduct"}
]
```

This is slammed by the compiler as not containing recognized actions on  the second line, but when I reformat it it works without any issues

```
TypeHandler := [ {"pattern": "=[0-z]*", "callback": "HandleEIN"}, {"pattern": "&[0-z]*", "callback": "HandleProduct"} ]
```

Now, this solution does work but it's quite clumsy and really feels like a hack, besides it's a pain to read when the array becomes more than five items long.

I've experimented with simpler arrays too, like

```
TypeHandler := [ 1, 2, 4, 3 ]
```

and the issue persists.

I've read through the [doc](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Arrays.htm) page but there is no mention of a limitation like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AHK joins lines that begin with a comma. This isn't perfectly ideal in terms of formatting your data, but it does allow for some level of multi-line arrays for increased readability.

Transformed examples:

```
;First Example
TypeHandler := [{"pattern": "=[0-z]*", "callback": "HandleEIN"}  
,{"pattern": "&[0-z]*", "callback": "HandleProduct"}]
```

```
;Second (Simplified) Example
arr :=  [1
        ,2
        ,3]
```

Comment: Does this work with all types of statements or only arrays?

Comment: See https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#continuation

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer explains line continuation with a comma, but I think it's worth mentioning that line continuation works with many other things as well.

Extract from the [documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#continuation-line):

> A line that starts with "and", "or",  ||, &&, a comma, or a [period](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#concat) is automatically merged with the line directly above it (in v1.0.46+, the same is true for all other [expression operators](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Operators) except ++ and --).

I also definitely think [continuation sections](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#continuation-section) deserve a mention here, since they're really cool and useful.
You can pretty much format your object however you want, as long as you understand how continuation sections work.

To get the formatting you were hoping for, you could do this:

```
TypeHandler := 
(Join
[
  {"pattern": "=[0-z]*", "callback": "HandleEIN"},
  {"pattern": "&[0-z]*", "callback": "HandleProduct"}
]
)
```

---

As a bonus, continuation sections can be made quite complex and cool, as long as you know what you're doing:

```
TypeHandler := [{base: b := {__Call: Func("__C")}}.(
(Join),{base:b}.( C 
"=[0-z]*",  "HandleEIN"       ; key,value pairs here
"&[0-z]*",  "HandleProduct"   ; key being the pattern
"\+[A-z]*", "HandleSmth1"     ; value being the callback
"\.[0-7]*", "HandleSmth2")]   ; last one needs to end with )]
)
__C(i,_,k,v) 
{ return (i, i.pattern := k, i.callback := v, ObjSetBase(i, ""))
}

; show output that it indeed works
for each, type in TypeHandler
    outp .= "pattern: " type.pattern " callback: " type.callback "`n"
MsgBox, % outp
```

I'm not going to try document this, as it has quite a few complex things in it, and I'd say it's pretty stupid as well since it's unnecessarily hard to understand.
Just showing it as an example that continuation sections can be really powerful/cool.